# VeeValidate multiple password constraints

Tags: validation, vue.js, passwords, vee-validate

I'm wondering if it's possible to have multiple password requirements passed to VeeValidate in order to display which requirements a user is missing.

For instance, if we require that a user's password should have at least one uppercase letter and at least one number and be at least 5 characters long, and the user types in "a1bb", we'd like to be able to display two error messages; one associated with the length requirement not being met and one related to the uppercase requirement not being met.

Ultimately, we'd like to be able to do something like this:
[image]

Would that be possible with VeeValidate? Or are there any examples of a similar approach?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer now, but I think you should give a look at https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/components/validation-provider.html#scoped-slot-data

Comment: I'm also interested if someone have already done what you asked

Comment: You might find [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VeeValidate allows you to display multiple errors fields but you need to disable the `fastExist` config option first:

> VeeValidate **only generates one message per field by default** as it uses
>   a fast-exit strategy when running the validation pipeline. [...] To disable this behavior you may want to configure the
>   fastExit option in VeeValidate's config or use the continues modifier. ([source](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/displaying-errors.html#displaying-errors))

---

For the rules you want to apply to password, you can use the existing **[`min`](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#min)** rule for the minimum length.

For the other rules (check upcase, lowercase, special char and digit), it's about regex check. VeeValidate actually provides a `regex` rule but in your case you need multiple ones.

So you need to define **[custom rules](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/custom-rules.html#using-the-custom-rule)**. I put some examples in the snippet below in the `created` hook but you also can define them globally.

---

In my example, I create a method to return a css class `error` by checking the errors by rule name.([source](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/api/errorbag.html#api))
Now the style is yours.

```js
const config = {
  fastExit: false
}
Vue.use(VeeValidate, config)

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return { password: '' }
  },
  created() {
    this.$validator.extend('upCase', {
      getMessage: () => "One uppercase character",
      validate: value => value.match(/[A-Z]/g) !== null
    })
    this.$validator.extend('number', {
      getMessage: () => "One number",
      validate: value => value.match(/[0-9]/g) !== null
    })
  },
  methods: {
    errorClass(rule) {
      return {
        'error': this.errors.firstByRule('password', rule)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
li {
  color: #B1B1B1;
}
li.error {
  color: #262626;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@2.0.0-rc.19/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-validate="'min:8|number|upCase'" name="password" >
  <ul>
    <li :class="errorClass('upCase')">One uppercase character</li>
    <li :class="errorClass('number')">One number</li>
    <li :class="errorClass('min')">8 characters minimum</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this solution

make a custom rule form VEEVALIDATE

STRONG PASSWORD VALIDATION

http://frankclark.xyz/veevalidate-strong-password-and-confirmation-validation